# Php Function to send SMS via Kannel

Tags: php, linux, function, kannel

I can now send an SMS via kannel. However this is done via headers eg:

```
header("Location:http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&to=$in_number&text=$in_msg");
```

I want to send an sms via a php function and I got the code below online but it doesn't work. (Kannel smsbox log shows no request):

```
  function sendSmsMessage($in_number, $in_msg)
 {
 $url = '/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=' . CONFIG_KANNEL_USER_NAME
 . '&password=' . CONFIG_KANNEL_PASSWORD    
 . '&charset=UCS-2&coding=2'
 . "&to={$in_number}"
 . '&text=' . urlencode(iconv('utf-8', 'ucs-2', $in_msg));



$results = file('http://'  
                 . CONFIG_KANNEL_HOST . ':'
                 . CONFIG_KANNEL_PORT . $url);
```

}

Is there something wrong? I tried replacing the CONFIG_KANNEL_USER_NAME and the rest with the actual values but it still doesn't work. Open to suggestions.

Comment: `echo 'http://'.CONFIG_KANNEL_HOST.':'.CONFIG_KANNEL_PORT.$url;` and try to request it for first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used cURL and it works 100% okay. file_get_contents does not work for me because I want to pass variables to the kannel url and file_get_contents does not process variables coz it insists on using single quotes(php treats it as a string value) instead of double quotes(php will parse the string checking for variables etc).
Here is what i am currently doing assuming you already have your variables initialized somewhere:

$textmsg="Hello Stackoverflow Users!";

$cellphone_number = "+254xxxxxxx"

$encmsg=urlencode($textmsg);

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&to=$cellphone_number&text=$encmsg");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This will work for the simple task of telling kannel to send an sms to a number. Took me a while to realize curl does not recognize spaces and special characters :-).

Comment: You need to have curl installed and php running with cURL support. For linux you do sudo apt-get install php5-curl. if you check phpinfo() you should see curl somewhere.

Comment: curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given. This is the error I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

My friend and I from Ndola, Zambia are using ubuntu 11.04 to run kannel_1.4.3. It works perfectly way in sending and receiving sms. The code below had to be edited for it to send more that 70 characters. My friend and I struggled to figure out that there was a small error in the line  '&charset=UCS-2&coding=2'. The correct line should be '&charset=UCS-2&encoding=2'. So the code should appear as below:

```
 function sendSmsMessage($in_number, $in_msg)
 {
 $url = '/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=' . CONFIG_KANNEL_USER_NAME
 . '&password=' . CONFIG_KANNEL_PASSWORD    
 . '&charset=UCS-2&encoding=2'
 . "&to={$in_number}"
 . '&text=' . urlencode(iconv('utf-8', 'ucs-2', $in_msg));
```

Comment: I'm from Kenya and I use UBUNTU 10.04.3. I'll definately try this function

Answer (score 1):

Using curl:

```
curl_init("http://$gw_host:$gw_port/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=$gw_user&password=$gw_pass&to=$to&from=$shortcode&smsc=$smsc&dlr-mask=$dlrmask&binfo=$shortcode&text=$message");
```

Replace the various variables/parameters with your values such as:

```
$gw_host=127.0.0.1
$gw_port=13xx3
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to trigger a URL loading in the background (rather than by re-directing the user to the URL), you need to use something like [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or perhaps even [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

For example, if your set up has fopen URL wrappers enabled, you could simply use:

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&to=$in_number&text=$in_msg");
```

Irrespective, it's hard to know why the function you found won't work without some additional debug information. (If CONFIG_KANNEL_HOST is defined as "localhost" and CONFIG_KANNEL_PORT is defined as 13013 then it's effectively doing the same thing, albeit with additional character set operations.)

Comment: That file_get_contents seems to work except that it reads the $in_number as part of the string instead of a variable. double quotes solves the variable issue but then file_get_contents() requires a string which is defined by single quotes. Is there a way to pass the variables directly to the string? thanks

Comment: @Max file_get_contents doesn't require a string with single quotes - single and double quotes are interchangeable in PHP, as long as they're used consistently within a single construct. (The different between the two being that double quotes will evaluate any embedded variables, etc.) As such, simply change the single quotes to double quotes and all should be well. :-)

Comment: Trust me. They aren't interchangeable. I've tried. Trying to use cURL

Answer (score 0):

Not to ressucitate an ancient question, but for posteriority and others searching for the same thing:

```
    [root@sat2 tools]# cat kannel-send.php 
    <?php

    function send_sms($msgid, $numto, $msgtext, $smsc = "smsc-default", $dlrmask = 63)
    {

            $sendsmsurl_prefix = "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms";
            $dlrurl_prefix = "http://localhost/tools/kannel-receive.php";
            $username = "user";
            $password = "pass";

            # fix number to what carriers expect
            $numto = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $numto);
            $numto = preg_replace('/^\+55/', '', $numto);
            $numto = "0" . $numto;

            if (!$msgid) $dlrmask = 0;

            $dlrurl_params = array(
                    "type" => "dlr",
                    "timesent" => "%t",
                    "smsc" => "%i",
                    "uuid" => "%I",
                    "fid" => "%F",
                    "dlr-cod" => "%d",
                    "reply" => "%A",
                    "msgid" => $msgid,
                    "text" => "%a",
                    "to" => "%P",
                    "from" => "%p",
                    "origsmsc" => "%f",
            );

            $dlrurl = $dlrurl_prefix . "?" . urldecode(http_build_query($dlrurl_params));

            $sendsmsurl_params = array(
                    "username" => $username,
                    "password" => $password,
                    "to" => $numto,
                    "dlr-mask" => $dlrmask,
                    "dlr-url" => $dlrurl,
                    "smsc"=> $smsc,
                    "text" => $msgtext,
            );

            $sendsmsurl = $sendsmsurl_prefix . "?" . http_build_query($sendsmsurl_params);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sendsmsurl);
            $bogus = curl_exec($ch);
            $ret = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $ret == "";

    }

    ?>
```

And you could have this other one to receive sms and store it to mysql:

```
    [root@sat2 tools]# cat kannel-receive.php 
    <?php

    $debug = false;

    $link = null;

    function dbconnect()
    {
            global $link, $debug;

            if ($link && mysql_ping($link))
                    return;

            if ($debug) echo "Conectando ao banco de dados\n";
            // TODO: criar um usuario de banco especifico pra isso
            $host = 'localhost';
            $user = 'user';
            $pass = 'pass';
            $db = 'dbname';
            $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, true);
            if (!$link){ 
                    if ($debug) echo "Can't connect to mysql: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
            } else {
                    mysql_select_db($db, $link);
            }
            return;
    }

    function esc($str)
    {
            global $link;
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str, $link);
    }

    if ($debug) {
            echo "<br>Kannel inbound sms event:<br>\n";
            var_dump($_GET);
    }

    dbconnect();

    if ($_GET['type'] == "inbsms") {

            $_GET['from'] = preg_replace('/^(\+55|0)/', '', $_GET['from']);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO notificacao (tipo, endereco, mensagem, device,
                            dataEvento, situacao)
                    VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')";
            $sql = sprintf($sql, 'sms', esc($_GET['from']), esc($_GET['text']),
                    esc($_GET['smsc']), esc($_GET['timesent']), "received");

    } elseif ($_GET['type'] == "dlr") {

            switch (esc($_GET['dlr-cod'])) {
            case "1":
                    $sql = "UPDATE notificacao SET 
                                    situacao = 'confirmed',
                                    dataConfirmacao = '{$_GET['timesent']}'
                            WHERE idnotificacao = {$_GET['msgid']}";
                    break;
            case "8":
                    $sql = "UPDATE notificacao SET 
                                    situacao = 'sent',
                                    device = '{$_GET['smsc']}',
                                    dataEvento = '{$_GET['timesent']}'
                            WHERE idnotificacao = {$_GET['msgid']}";
                    break;
            case "16":
                    $sql = "UPDATE notificacao SET 
                                    situacao = 'failed',
                                    device = '{$_GET['smsc']}',
                                    razaofalha = '{$_GET['reply']}',
                                    dataEvento = '{$_GET['timesent']}'
                            WHERE idnotificacao = {$_GET['msgid']}";
                    break;
            }

    }

    if ($debug) echo "sql: $sql\n";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    if (!$result) {
            if ($debug) echo "Erro sql: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
    }

    ?>
```

This one doubles as a SMS receiver and a SMS-Delivery-Notification receiver (in that case it updates a record on the database that was put there when sending the sms, to confirm it was received).

It's used for DLR because I send the URL for that when sending the SMS (and set the DLR mask asking for confirmation), but for inbound SMS you have to configure your kannel.conf to use it (you can have many sms-service, this is just an example of a catch-all one:

```
    [...]
    group = sms-service
    keyword = default
    get-url = "http://localhost/tools/kannel-receive.php?type=inbsms&text=%a&timesent=%t&from=%p&to=%P&smsc=%i&uuid=%I&delivery=%d&service=%n&encoding=%c&class=%m&mwi=%M&charset=%C&udh=%u&dcs=%O&origsmsc=%f"
    catch-all = yes
    max-messages = 0
    accept-x-kannel-headers = true
    concatenation = yes
    omit-empty = yes
    [...]
```

Sorry for some texts in portuguese, but you can get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

//php code file name is test2.php.before that,you must install php5-curl on ubuntu14